# Does MSSQL Server acquire locks even without an explicit transaction?

Tags: sql-server, locking, transactions, concurrency

I was reading about MSSQL Locking for the first time, and it many places, the locking mechanism concepts depend on the existence of Transactions. I was wondering whether locking (in general) is possible without having any Transactions involved?